# How to hot deploy Maven Web project in Netbeans on Save (Ctrl+s)?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Netbeans Version: 8.0.2

JDK: 1.8

Project Type: .WAR (Web Project)

Following are settings done with netbeans IDE:

```
* In Maven Project, Right clicked -> Properties -> Build -> Compile -> Compile on Save (Ticked).
* In Maven Project, Right clicked -> Properties -> Run -> Deploy on Save (Ticked).
* Added following to POM.XML:
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <unzip src="target/gave.war" dest="D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.18\webapps/gave"/>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now i am doing Changes are done in .js file and saved the file (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>).

But building is not happening and neither changes reflected in application.

When I need to right click on project and build explicitly then only i am able to Build and Deploy automatically.

Is there any way to Build and Deploy on Save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)

Comment: Right click the project name -> Properties -> Build -> Compiling. There you can select "Compile on save" option (if you use Ant) or select "Enable" (if you use Maven). That will do the build but you still need to deploy the project :)

Comment: @Arkantos

I think i have mentioned this in very first line in settings done. Are you referring to same or something different? "compile on save" is already checked but it is not compiling on saving